# Code doesn't work in Visual studio, but work in C++ shell and CodeBlock, compiler issue?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void print_message(char *s) {
    cout << s << "\n";
}
int main()
{
    print_message("hello"); 
    print_message("world");
}
```

This code doesn't work in Visual studio, gives two error: error C2015: too many characters in constant
, error C2664: 'void print_message(char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'char *'
Butut work in C++ shell and CodeBlock, compiler issue?

Comment: The compiler in Code::Blocks is wrong. Probably an old compiler that allowed this conversion.

Comment: Is this actually the code you compiled? You'd get those error messages if you used `'` quotes instead of `"`. The code shown here would result in different errors.

Comment: [Pro Tip] When compiling, use the `-pedantic`(gcc, clang)/`/permissive-`(msvs) flags to make the compiler strictly conform to the C++ standard.

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-096-introduction-to-c-january-iap-2011/ Is this courses old, similar error encountered in some of the code shown.

Comment: If the answer below solves the problem, I would appreciate it if you mark it as answer and this will be beneficial to other community. Also, if you are studying C++ independently, I suggest that you could refer to [Microsoft Docs about C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not allowed to convert a string literal to a `char *`. Your function needs to accept a `char const *` like this:

```
void print_message(char const *s) {
    cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zqz93z).